# firefox stats - library

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, canvas

anyone knows what is library chart  used the firefox stats?

http://glow.mozilla.org/#arc

thanks

Comment: why i can't open the glow.mozilla.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a library, but you can find its project page on [Github here](https://github.com/potch/glow/).